# Android Shared Preferences with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-studio, collections, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save and retrieve an ArrayList as shared preference.

I have three items in my ArrayList named `arra` ,but when I try to add the values in Set in the `set.addAll(arr)`, only two items get added.

Are there any corrections that can be one in the following code so I can save the arraylist correctly as shared preferences.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet(filename, null);
                    arra = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (String str : set)
                       arra.add(str);
```

Saving of ArrayList

```
 SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=prefs.edit();

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(arr);
        edit.putStringSet(filename, set);
        edit.commit();
```

Comment: What are the exact contents of the array you're trying to save?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson ArrayList of Strings.

Comment: What are the exact strings?

Comment: Refer old StackOverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm trying to save checkbox data as true and false strings in an array.Can i store similar values in the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to store boolean true and false values as strings.  This means you can only have two possible strings, "true" and "false".  Set type containers only store unique values - there are no duplicates.  So in your set you will only have up to two different values, "true" and "false".

If you want to store a list, you might want to convert that into a string somehow so that the actual values and order are preserved.  Then when reading that value out, parse the string to reconstruct the list.

Answer (score 3):

The **Set** in java collections **does not allow duplicate entries** to be inserted and two out of the three items in your ArrayList are the same. This is the reason for only two of them being saved in the SharedPreferences.